# Angular 2 - 404 provider issue

Tags: angular, angular2-providers

I'm having a problem while I'm trying to add a provider in my Angular 2 application. I was trying some solutions I found online but I can't figure out what is going on with my app.

Basically I'm getting the problem when I add the provider to my code:

- GET http://localhost:3000/dist/services/performances.service 404 (Not Found)
- Error: (SystemJS) XHR error (404 Not Found) loading http://localhost:3000/dist/services/performances.service(…)

**Note:** I have checked the paths are ok, and visual code doesn't provide me any error.

In the image below you can see the output o my app.

Application output 
[image]

The service I'm trying to add: (performances.service.ts)

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {Performance} from '../common/performance';
import {PERFORMANCES} from '../data/data-performances';

@Injectable()
export class PerformancesService {
    private performances : any;

    contructor(){
        this.performances = {};
    }

    getData(){
        return this.performances = PERFORMANCES;
    }
}
```

My app.component.ts

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {PerformancesService} from '../services/performances.service';

@Component({
  selector : 'my-app',
  template:
  `
    <header-fund-centre></header-fund-centre>
    <div class="container">
      <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    </div>
  `,
  providers: [PerformancesService]
})

export class AppComponent { }
```

systemjs.config.js

```
(function (global) {
  System.config({
    paths: {
      'npm:': 'node_modules/'
    },
    // map tells the System loader where to look for things
    map: {
      // our app is within the app folder
      app: 'app',
      // angular bundles
      '@angular/core': 'npm:@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js',
      '@angular/common': 'npm:@angular/common/bundles/common.umd.js',
      '@angular/compiler': 'npm:@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js',
      '@angular/platform-browser': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser/bundles/platform-browser.umd.js',
      '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/bundles/platform-browser-dynamic.umd.js',
      '@angular/http': 'npm:@angular/http/bundles/http.umd.js',
      '@angular/router': 'npm:@angular/router/bundles/router.umd.js',
      '@angular/forms': 'npm:@angular/forms/bundles/forms.umd.js',
      // other libraries
      'rxjs':                      'npm:rxjs',
      'angular-in-memory-web-api': 'npm:angular-in-memory-web-api',
      // Styling
      '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap': 'node_modules/@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/bundles/ng-bootstrap.js',
    },
    // packages tells the System loader how to load when no filename and/or no extension
    packages: {
      app: {
        main: '../dist/main.js',
        defaultExtension: 'js'
      },
      rxjs: {
        defaultExtension: 'js'
      },
      'angular-in-memory-web-api': {
        main: './index.js',
        defaultExtension: 'js'
      }
    }
  });
})(this);
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong to have this problem adding a basic provider? Thanks!

**Edited**

Below you can see all the dependencies I'm currently using

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "~2.1.1",
    "@angular/compiler": "~2.1.1",
    "@angular/core": "~2.1.1",
    "@angular/forms": "~2.1.1",
    "@angular/http": "~2.1.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~2.1.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~2.1.1",
    "@angular/router": "~3.1.1",
    "@angular/upgrade": "~2.1.1",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^1.0.0-alpha.14",
    "angular-in-memory-web-api": "~0.1.13",
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.7",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.8",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.12",
    "systemjs": "0.19.39",
    "zone.js": "^0.6.25"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/core-js": "^0.9.34",
    "@types/node": "^6.0.45",
    "concurrently": "^3.0.0",
    "lite-server": "^2.2.2",
    "typescript": "^2.0.3"
  }
```

Comment: Try to add `.js` extension to your import in your app.component ? `import {PerformancesService} from '../services/performances.service.js';`

Comment: @Soywod it doesn't work, and doesnt make sense do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thing I can't see `.ts` file in your folder, Kindly make sure your `performances.service.ts` is present in `services` folder.

Change map's `map` to below

```
map: {
    // our app is within the app folder
    app: 'dist', //<-- changed from 'app' to 'dist
    ...
}
```

Change your `packages` option to below, saying `dist` is package

```
packages: {
  dist: {
    main: 'main.js', //<-- change here, just used shorthand
    defaultExtension: 'js'
  },
  ...
}
```

Add `PerformancesService` to `providers` option of `NgModule` so that DI system will recognize the dependency while creating instance of it.

```
providers: [ PerformancesService ]
```

Comment: what you said its working, but now I'm getting the following error: ``Error: (SystemJS) Can't resolve all parameters for PerformanceComponent: (?)`` any idea how to solve it? I saw the problem is when I add the service to my constructor in the component ``constructor(private PerformanceService : PerformancesService){}``

Comment: @gon250 1st tell whats angular 2 version you are using? It seems like its not angular 2 final atleast

Comment: I have edited my question and added the dependencies. thanks!

Comment: @gon250 haven't you created `NgModule`?

Comment: here is the ``NgModule`` http://paste.ofcode.org/EMT2T86N9rKaDAc9uDRZ8A

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129557/discussion-between-gon250-and-pankaj-parkar).